# Regex Remove everything after / except when certain string exists

Tags: java, regex

I have certain urls that I am trying to shorten. I want to remove all everything after the / of the url except when that url is equal to `plus.google.com`

For example:

`www.somerubbish.com/about/64848372.meh.php` will shorten to `www.somerubbish.com`

`plus.google.com/756934692387498237/about` will be left untouched

Any ideas on how I can do this?

My failed attempt is below. I know that the | is saying OR so thats why it is matching the / in the first line as well.

```
\b!(?:plus.google.com\/.*)\b|\b(?:\/.*)\b
```

http://regexr.com/3cv6n

Comment: first step, choose a regex tester that supports the java regex flavor: regexplanet.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have it.

The answer was to use a negative lookbehind and remove the pipe

```
(?<!plus.google.com)\b(?:\/.*)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/pU3hU4/1

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
if( ! url.contains("plus.google.com")) {
    url = StringUtils.substringBefore(url, "/");
}
```

Comment: I have regex doing a lot of things and was trying to get everything working in one go. I have something similar to that working right now as a temporary measure. plus.google.com is not the only one I want to leave alone and would prefer not to have a massive if statement with pipes in it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11549068)

Comment: @JohannesJander The OP said, "Any ideas on how I can do this?" Absolutely my answer is "an idea how to do this"  :P

Comment: @Stewart Whenever I find myself starting an answer with "what's wrong with...", I have the feeling I am missing something in the question, so I make this a comment.

Comment: That doesn't make it "not an answer." I think it's valuable to point out that regex isn't the only way to go, in this case.